# Trying to install ssh2 on php

Tags: php, ssh, pecl

Firstly I'm running PHP 5.3.3, CentOS 5.7 (2.6.18-274.3.1.el5xen)

Secondly, I basically have no idea what I'm doing... sorry!

First of all I installed libssh2 from http://www.libssh2.org/.  Ran configure, make, make install.  Don't really understand all of this stuff, but following online instructions seemed to work.

Then ran

```
pecl install ssh2
```

So far so good.

Added the relevant extension line to php.ini, as instructed.  Restarted apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

All good.

But then can't find any reference to ssh in phpInfo().

Tried

```
php -m | grep ssh2
```

and got the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so: undefined symbol: libssh2_sftp_readdir_ex in Unknown on line 0
```

What have I done wrong/missed out, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you add the line to the correct php.ini file?

Comment: FYI http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.configuration.php

Comment: I did rich.  If I hadn't it wouldn't be trying to load the extension and there'd be no error possible! :)

Comment: Where do I find the ssh2.c file it mentions @liquorvicar?  When I unpack the tar.gz file there's a /test/ssh2.c and /example/ssh2.c?  I checked again after "configure" and "make" and no new copies of the file appeared anywhere.  Neither of those files sound right from the directory names, and they don't contain the lines specified in the link you gave? :(

Comment: @Codemonkey I'm no expert on the inner workings of PECL as anything I've ever had to install has worked out of the box but my guess would be PECL comes with an ssh2.c file. Maybe someone who knows more about PECL can clarify if that's true and if so how you download the PECL module and change the file before installing.

Comment: I'm certain CentOS has a system package for that.

Comment: restart you ssh. `/ssh restart`

Comment: @mario: If it does, I couldn't find it.

Comment: @liquidvicor: I checked the PECL package and did find a more relevant ssh2.c in it, but it was already missing line 53 (and 52 for that matter).  Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: @Wyck: how?  I fuond ssh in /usr/bin/, but running ssh restart gives "ssh: restart: Name or service not known".  I found sshd in /etc/init.d but couldn't do much with that either?  Sorry for my newbness.

Comment: At the very least libssh2 exists as package and matching -dev package. And use alternative sources then for the PHP modules: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17052077/dir/redhat_el_6/com/php-pecl-ssh2-0.11.3-1.el6.remi.i686.rpm.html

Comment: @Wyck: ok, I ran "service sshd restart", which ran fine, but didn't change the error message.  I restarted apache too, for good measure.

Comment: "yum search ssh2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
==================================================== Matched: ssh2 =====================================================
jsch.x86_64 : Pure Java implementation of SSH2
libssh2.x86_64 : Library implementing the SSH2 protocol
libssh2-devel.i386 : Header files, libraries and development documentation for libssh2
libssh2-devel.x86_64 : Header files, libraries and development documentation for libssh2"

Comment: If I try to install any of those libssh2 entries I get "Setting up Install Process" and "Nothing to do" :(

Comment: (those libssh2 entries weren't there in yum either - I had to manually add a repo from somewhere to get them...)

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem with CentOs 6.3, and I followed this [guide](http://darxness.com/blog/?p=1216) a bit differently.

1) Install needed packages:

```
yum install automake make php-devel libtool openssl-devel gcc++ gcc
```

2) Change directory (`/usr/lib/php` if you have a 32bit OS):

```
cd /usr/lib64/php
```

3) Download the source (latest as of 2013/02/28, check latest [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)):

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-0.12.tgz
```

4) Create a build directory (I don't like mess in my system) and untar the package:

```
mkdir build-dir
mv ssh2-0.12.tgz build-dir
cd build-dir
tar xzvf ssh2-0.12.tgz
```

5) Prepare the compile step and compile:

```
phpize
./configure –with-ssh2
make
```

6) Copy the module in the system (`/usr/lib/php/modules/ssh2.so` if you have a 32bit OS):

```
cp modules/ssh2.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so
```

7) Change configuration and add this line to `/etc/php.d/ssh2.ini` (although I didn't need to do this on my setup, maybe because I had already done this in the past):

```
extension=ssh2.so
```

8) If you want you can delete the build directory:

```
cd ../../
rm -f build-dir
```