# ssh2.so unable to load on CentOS 5

Tags: php, ssh, centos5, libssh

I've been trying to install the SSH2 libraries for php onto a web server running CentOS 5 with PHP 5.1.6 and was able to successfully install all the dependencies, but after restarting the web server I get the following error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' - libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Has anyone run into this before?  The ssh2.so file exists at '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so' and has the same file permissions as all the other extensions (-rwxr-xr-x).

Thanks

Comment: Is selinux enabled? If so, does it have the correct context label?

Comment: Selinux is currently disabled.

Answer (score -1):

The key to the error is this:

```
libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Your ssh2.so file can't find it. Run this and you'll see what I mean:

```
ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/ssh2.so
```

Try this:

```
updatedb
locate libssh2.so.1
```

If found, you may need to create a symlink inside /usr/lib64/ or something.

If that doesn't find it, a quick google search brings up this as a hit for libssh2 on centos5:

http://centos.karan.org/el5/extras/testing/x86_64/RPMS/libssh2-0.18-10.el5.kb.x86_64.rpm

Install that, restart apache, and try it again.

Comment: Adding the symbolic link returns: `PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'ssh2.so' in Unknown on line 0` and I have already installed libssh2

Comment: To resolve this, I installed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535885/trying-to-install-ssh2-on-php/15138640#15138640

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), would work better for you?  An example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```